# Cypress intercept doesn't match wildcard params and query params

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am having an issue with cypress intercept method. I want to intercept any request made with this url 'https://p13a79.fra1.a.restack.io/' as a prefix. I also tried with a regex '^https://p13a79.fra1.a.restack.io/.*$' which also didn't work

```
describe('Consent banner test: allow', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.intercept(
      'https://p13a79.fra1.a.restack.io/*'
    ).as('consentRequest') 
  });

  it('I can accept the consent banner', () => {
    
    cy.visit('https://www.deepskydata.com/');
    
 

    cy.wait('@consentRequest')
    cy.get("[data-testid='uc-banner-content']").should('be.visible').log("Consent banner visible");
    cy.get("[data-testid='uc-deny-all-button']").should('be.visible').log("Deny all button visible");
    cy.get("[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']").should('be.visible').log("Allow all button visible");
    cy.get("[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']").click();
    cy.wait('@consentRequest')

  });
});
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a glob expression

```js
cy.intercept(
  'https://p13a79.fra1.a.restack.io/**'
).as('consentRequest')
```

Comment: This worked but what's weird is that I tried this before, and it didn't work in the first time.

Comment: @ElVincitore how odd, glad it's working now though, I normally end up splitting it out into a route matcher - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#routeMatcher-RouteMatcher